# Como comunicarme con un dispositivo conectado en lan

Tags: c#

Buenas, estoy trasteando con un sensor de huella biométrica, mi intención es conseguir volcar los datos mediante un programa. Pero me he encontrado que para empezar, a pesar de que puedo hacerle ping, no consigo comunicarme con él usando la clase Socket.

```
static void ProbarConexion(){

            Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,
   ProtocolType.Tcp);


            s.Connect("192.168.1.224", 52925);

            if (!s.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Imposible conectar");
            }

            if (s.Poll(-1, SelectMode.SelectWrite))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Se puede escribir");
            }
            else if (s.Poll(-1, SelectMode.SelectRead))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Se puede leer");
            }
            else if (s.Poll(-1, SelectMode.SelectError))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
            }

        }
```

Alguna idea? De ese código me salta una exepción de que no se ha podido responder.

Decir que en el dispositivo lo tengo configurado con la dirección ip y el puerto que he puesto en el código, vamos, que hacer ping usando el cmd va bien.

Comment: que error recibes cuando intenta conectar la clase socket ? realizas un ping a la ip, pero como sabes que el puerto esta accesible?  validaster que el firewall de windows no lo este bloqueando ?

Comment: Recibo este error: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException was unhandled
  Message=Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder 192.168.1.224:52925

Comment: validaste lo que comente del firewall de windows ? puede que la ip responda pero que el puerto este bloqueado para su acceso

Comment: He descubierto que el aparato utiliza un protocolo de tipo ARP, por lo tanto no podemos hablar de conectado o no, ahora falta saber como hacer para volcar los datos de ahí a mi pc.

Answer (score 1):

**>>el aparato utiliza un protocolo de tipo ARP,**

Podrias usar las api de windows para enviar por medio de `ARP`

[Create page SendARP (iphlpapi)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.SendARP)

defines

```
 [DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", ExactSpelling=true)]
 public static extern int SendARP(
    uint DestIP, uint SrcIP, byte[] pMacAddr, ref int PhyAddrLen);
```

Lo raro es que esto no se usa para enviar datos a un dispositivo

[Protocolo de resolución de direcciones](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_de_resoluci%C3%B3n_de_direcciones)

Mira lo que comenta la wiki

> El protocolo ARP se encarga de traducir las direcciones IP a direcciones MAC (direcciones físicas). Para realizar esta conversión, el nivel de enlace utiliza las tablas ARP, cada interfaz tiene tanto una dirección IP como una dirección física MAC.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Pues entonces ya me quedo sin ideas de cómo extraer los datos del aparato, porque viene sin SDK ni nada con lo que poder trabajar, simplemente se que se puede conectar mediante un rj45 y tiene un software propio, pero no vale gran cosa.

Comment: no puedes contatar al fabricante ? si tiene un sector de soporte podria darte una idea de como cominicarte con el dispositivo

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que esos dispositivos biometricos tienen su propio programa de comunicación, y seguro estas tratando de "hackearlo".

Te recomiendo que descargues wireshark, lo pongas a grabar, y comuniques el programa de fabricante con el dispositivo, de esa manera podras ver el puerto, protocolo (TCP o UDP), y tal vez algun detalle de como hacer comandos

Comment: He probado tu consejo y he descubierto que el aparato funciona con un protocolo de tipo ARP, entonces ahora me falta saber como conseguir pasar los datos a mi pc. Algún consejo?

Comment: NO, ARP se usa para descubrir un dispositivo (hacer un ping por APIs), pero despues de eso debe haber más comunicacion. Es decir, lo que vistes solo es el programa detectando el dispositivo. ARP no se usa para comunicar, debes ver algo TCP o UDP